# Displaying TinyMCE tables for WYSIWYG Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, tinymce, wysiwyg

When I draw a table by TinyMCE for Drupal, the table doesn't display properly in my page. I get just the text with no border and without the right order of columns and rows. How can I solve that?

For example, I get something like this:

```non
col 1 
col 2 
col 3

data
data
data
```

instead of:

```non
col 1   col 2   col 3
data    data    data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the HTML is filtered before rendering it on the page. Verify if the `Limit allowed HTML tags` is checked / enabled. If so, you need to add the table HTML tags into `Allowed HTML tags` configuration (under the vertical tabs).

Go to `Configuration` > `Content Authoring` > `Text formats` > `{your used format}` > `Configure`

I usually use these tags in my websites configuration which covers the classic content HTML tags for webmasters / content editors:

```
<p> <a> <em> <strong> <cite> <blockquote> <code> <ul> <ol> <li> <dl> <dt> <dd> <h2> <h3> <h4> <h5> <h6> <span> <img> <br> <table> <thead> <tbody> <tfoot> <tr> <th> <td>
```